# Elixir language: syntax error when trying to unzip a list. What is missing?

Tags: list, algorithm, functional-programming, elixir

Anyone who can help.

I am a beginner in Elixir Language. I am trying to perform an “`unzip`” operation and the “`iex`” environment shows syntax error “`syntax error before: ')'`” at position “`53`” of the script, I am writing. I know the algorithm works because I tested it on Haskell, but I cannot find where my syntax error is and what to do to resolve it.

This

```
defmodule Alf do
  def lastx([]), do: raise ArgumentError, message: "empty list"
  def lastx([x]), do: x
  def lastx([x | xs]), do: lastx(xs)

  def initx([]), do: raise ArgumentError, message: "empty list"
  def initx([x]), do: []
  def initx([x | xs]), do: [x | initx(xs)]

  def revx([]), do: []
  def revx(xs), do: [lastx(xs) | revx(initx(xs))]

  def zipx([], b), do: []
  def zipx(a, []), do: []
  def zipx([x | a], [y | b]), do: [{x, y} | zipx(a, b)]

  def fstx(x, _), do: x

  def sndx(_, y), do: y
end
```

Here is the part that is not working properly:

```
defmodule Alf do
  def unzipx_bs(xs, ys, []), do: (revx(xs), revx(ys))
  def unzipx_bs(xs, ys, [z | zs]), do: unzipx_bs([fstx z | xs], [sndx z | ys], zs)
end
```

The “`unzipx_bs`” script will later be set to private and will have a script called “unzipx” as the access interface that will perform the so-called “`unzipx_bs [], [], [{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3 , 6}]`” to generate a result similar to “`[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]`”.

Comment: How come you define module Alf twice?

Comment: As far as I can see  you call  `fstx` and `sndx` each with one argument when two arguments are expected. Perhaps the parser croaks because of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you wanted your `unzipx_bs` function to return a pair. Tuples are written with `{}` in elixir, so it should be `{revx(xs), revx(ys)}`. I would further propose that you unpack your `z` right there in the argument list, giving:

```elixir
def unzipx_bs(xs, ys, []), do: {revx(xs), revx(ys)}
def unzipx_bs(xs, ys, [{x, y} | zs]), do: unzipx_bs([x | xs], [y | ys], zs)
```

Then:

```elixir
Alf.unzipx_bs([], [], [{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}])
# => {[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, guidance, tip and dedicated time. May Heavenly Father bless you.